# Preg_match not working for following string "BE09879"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to fetch string in line that starts with "BE" followed by number and number could be of any digit.

I tried following code but it is matching only if there is 4 digits number. I need to match it for any digit.

```
$line = "ethernet card BE0987 strings allws";
preg_match('/BE([0-9]{4})/', $line, $match)
```

Any SUggestions ??

Comment: Your code works fine. Here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f46fca1f1b467a10fb98156c17b68f66a0fd1fb4

Answer (score 1):

That is becase ([0-9]{4}) tells regexp to match exaclty 4 digits. instead 
you could use this:

```
$line = "ethernet card BE0987 strings allws";
preg_match('/BE([0-9]*)/', $line, $match)
```

witch will match be followed by zero or more digits, or you can use:

```
$line = "ethernet card BE0987 strings allws";
preg_match('/BE([0-9]+)/', $line, $match)
```

witch will match be followed by at least one digit

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
$line = "ethernet card BE0987 strings allws";
preg_match('/BE([0-9][0-9]{4})/', $line, $match);
```

Or instead, why not give this way:

```
preg_match('/BE([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])/', $line, $match);
```

The above matches exactly 5 digits. Or, you can make it match at least one digit by this way:

```
preg_match('/BE([0-9]+)/', $line, $match);
```